# Generalization of relation on set

Tags: real-analysis

Is there any generalization of supremum?
I mean i have a subset "A"of set of natural number which has three element namely 4, 7 and 9.

(1) is that possible to define relation on set of natural number such that with respect to that relation supremum of set A is  7?
(2) to find supremum does we really need the universal set or we can define relation on particular set and with respect to that relation supremum can be determine.?
(3) supremum are defined for partially ordered set? Or total ordered set?or for both?
(4) if supremum are for total ordered set then it is for total ordered set or strict total ordered set?

Comment: For what its worth, you don't need relations to be defined according to some intuitive rule... it can be done quite arbitrarily with no deeper meaning attached.  That said, consider the relation "$a\prec b$ iff the largest prime dividing $a$ is less than the largest prime dividing $b$"

Comment: @JMoravitz. Yes w.r.t this relation supremum is 7.and i got it what u mean by rule. Can u plz try remaining questions?

Comment: Supremum can be defined for posets but not always it exists.

Comment: If your ordered set is not a subset of some larger set, then its supremum has to be a member of the set itself. When the supremum is contained within the set, it is called a "maximum". The definition of supremum is given in terms of a larger set because the concept is very useful in that context, where the supremum does not need to be in the set. However, there is no restriction against it being in the set. All maximums are supremums, but not all supremums are maximums.

Comment: @PaulSinclair can u try question no. 3 and 4?

Comment: Mateo has already answered 3 ("poset" = "Partially Ordered SET"). and I'm not even sure what you mean by "strict" total ordered set. That the order is "$<$" instead of "$\le$", maybe? If so, then it is a false distinction. Any order (at least partial, or stronger) has both strict and non-strict versions. Suprema for the strict and non-strict versions are exactly the same.

Comment: With a poset, there are two possible types of upper bound. I don't know any canonical terminology for them (there may be one - I just don't know it). Let me call them "full" and "semi" upper bounds. Each comes with its own concept of supremum. A full upper bound for a subset $S$ of a poset is an element $M$ of the poset such that for all $s \in S, s \le M$. A semi-upper bound is an element $m$ such that there is some $s \in S$ with $s \le m$ and there is no $s \in S$ with $m < s$. Both are suprema if there is no $x <M$ or $m$ that is also a full or semi upper bound.

Comment: The weakness of a full supremum $M$ is that there may be semi-upper bounds between $M$ and elements of $S$. In a sense $S$ may come nowhere near $M$. $M$ is just the point where the various branches $S$ lies across come together, which may be well above any member of $S$. The problem with semi-suprema is they are not unique, and there may be elements of $S$ that are not bounded by them at all.